# What is the ratio of $\frac {BK}{BE}$?

Tags: geometry

Here is my diagram

[image]

Here is what are given

$$|BD| = 2$$ $$|DC| = 5$$ $$|AE| = 2$$ $$|EC| = 3$$

- What is the ratio of $\frac {BK}{BE}$?

I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the construction I made in my picture below, it's easy to see that $BK=KE$ and therefore $\frac{BK}{KE}=1$

[image]

Comment: It seems great!

Answer (score 1):

Raffaele your statement that BK = KE is true, but the question asked for the ratio of BK to BE. Your diagram appears to be correct, but you set up the wrong ratio. So, the correct ratio of BK/BE is 2/4, or 1/2.